# Google Analytics: how to see event sequence for a given user

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to see all the events generated by a single user? In other words, is it possible to trace his/her actions on a page? The goal is to understand what a given user tried to do, as opposed to seeing a summary of all events.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can indeed, you can actually track everything user did how much time he spent what event he triggered, but every user on your site get a generic id number set by GA cookie, so if you have registration modal and specific privacy policy accepted by user you can even know which user did what and when. FOR the report just go to your view and than under audience click user explorer you shall see a list with some long generic numbers separeted with dot. This numbers are your user. Drill donw and enjoy